# Post MP3 and get click counts

Tags: mp3

I need to post a friend's MP3 (he owns the copyright) and then link to it from Facebook. If it were a movie, I would use YouTube to get trustworthy click counts, etc.

What website would allow me to get click counts even for anonymous users for an MP3 that I own the rights to?

**Edit:** What I'm really looking for is the best way to get public click counts for an arbitrary link that I post to a webserver. If that's not possible, I'd could upload the thing to someone else's webserver, like 4shared, but 4shared has a 30-day-you-must-login policy.

Comment: It's pretty easy to setup a site on http://sites.google.com, then analyze it with google analytics. https://www.google.com/analytics

Comment: Thanks Dave, I want PUBLIC click counts. I have a million ways to get analytics, but I want viewers to see these automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't see nothing wrong with youtube. It's not like there isn't a whole bunch of one picture-song in the background clips on it already ...

Comment: great point......+1

Comment: Kind of inelegant, though.

Comment: maybe ... BUT ... if the music is good, nobody's gonna care about the inelegancy of the site. if the music is bad, nobody's gonna care about the inelegancy of the site ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm not actually worried about the music or the site, elegancy wise (though to some web surfers, elegancy will matter). But I'd like to get some PUBLIC click counts Youtube style for MP3s, without having to make them into videos (which is a tad cheesy).

Answer (score 1):

If you friend is planning to produce more MP3's or possibly even an album, you might consider [Jamendo](http://www.jamendo.com/en/) - it's a site designed to help artists distribute their work.  Otherwise, go with Idigas.

Comment: @Idigas, I see it all now, thanks for that. What about share it sites and that?

Comment: You mean p2p, torrents and the like ? Or more like lastfm and such ? Wait, just clarify something for me please. Is the goal getting counts or promoting the mp3 ? I can't tell from the question. If it is promoting the music, I always found a nice example of an interface: http://www.billiethevision.com/music.php of how free music can be listened.

Comment: Idigas, yeah, good point, I guess the idea would be to promote the music in part, but I'm not that hot on actually doing any work on a site. I was wondering about sites like 4shared or imeem

Answer (score 1):

You might try getting an account at [bit.ly](http://bit.ly/) and then grabbing statistics from clicks on the shortened URL.

Comment: Yes, or www.linkee.com, but I'd like those stats to be public.

Comment: Ah, hmm. They do have an API, maybe you could get something out of that. Then again maybe you couldn't or it's not worth it.